# Automation testing with Meteor

Tags: meteor, cucumberjs

I am getting close doing something actually useful with Meteor. After being in war with NodeJS and Cucumber, I am finally at the stage of going beyond the boundaries of writing some Gherkinish - and as I am spoiled with the Ruby frameworks that provide automated testing facilities, such as Capybara, I wanted to ask which solution would fit in with Meteor, Flow Router, Blaze, Cucumber and CoffeeScript do such automation, simulating and uniform a real user's interaction with an meteor application.

Your feedback is truly appreciated!

Comment: There is a testing framework http://velocity.meteor.com/ but I have personally only stuck with the old school Tinytest libraries.

Comment: I am aware of velocity - however, I like Cucumber a lot. I know it is used in the community as well. Hence my question.

Comment: Velocity lets you use Cucumber. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Sir, I love you. Thought Velocity was something in combination with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity allows automated testing with Cucumber.